# Node.js client in android using webkit without webview

Tags: android, node.js, client-server

I'm trying to build a nodejs client and I don't find a good library for java or android. Till now I was not able to establish a valid connection. my server is node 0.10.

Since the browser supports a lot of protocols(even in android 2.2). Is it possible to eliminate the webview and use only the underlying library?

Otherwise is there any solution to display even the web view(but in a background activity or service) because my main activity uses 2D graphics. I know...the activity in background stops its execution and the service has no UI. But at least these are my ideas. :p

**Update**
I  managed to establish the connection using the
[Gottox's library](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client) that supports only websockets and XHR(beta).

Comment: why don't you use the HttpClient or the UrlConnection api ?

Comment: I need a push service. With these api can I use all the functionalities that are given by node? How can I access all the node's callbacks?

Comment: @artBCode Did you find any solution for this? I only got about the webkit engine but no more code.